# Android Spinner text color

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner, customization

I have a Spinner and for populating him i use a SimpleCursorAdapter.
I want the font color for spinner to be Black and font color for drop down to be White.
I have this code:

```
String[] column = { "name" };
int[] viewIds = new int[] { R.id.spinner_dropdown_design_from };

SimpleCursorAdapter fromListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MyClass.this, R.layout.spinner_drop_down_from, cursor,
        column, viewIds) {

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View viewFromListAdapter = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        viewFromListAdapter.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.dropdown_selector_odd);
    } else {
        viewFromListAdapter.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.dropdown_selector_even);
    }
    return viewFromListAdapter;
}
```

};

So i use different layout for odd and even rows in the dropdown.
I give you an example for dropdown_selector_even

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/grey_background"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue_background"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue_background"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/grey_background"/>
</selector>
```

And spinner_drop_down_from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/spinner_dropdown_design_from"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
    android:textSize="40dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" 
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.
I must also overwrite the getView method
Something like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_dropdown_design_products);
text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look to the following link. It worked for me, and not need to use custom adapters. Just xml.
http://www.broculos.net/2013/09/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-color.html#.U2eJI_l5OSo